# Arduino SSCANF stop on comma delimiter

Tags: arduino-uno, string, array

I have the following problem, the arduino is receiving a command like

**LCD,Display line text one, Display line text two**

I use an strcmp to match the beginning of the string that works but now I would like to ignore the beginning of the string (LCD) and scan in the next 2 variables until the comma to 2 new variables.

```
                sscanf(Command, "%[^,]%[^,]%[^,]", &dummy, &lcd_display_l1, &lcd_display_l2);
```

I don't know if it's possible to ignore the first variable (which would be the LCD) but I setup a dummy variable for it anyway what I not going to use.

All I get with this is the LCD in the dummy the other 2 does not fill up.
I have tried this syntax:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/38335

Doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `"%*[^,],%[^,],%[^,]"`. The asterisk is for ignoring the field.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `strtok()` to chop the string up:

```
char *prefix = strtok(mystring, ",");
char *firstString = strtok(NULL, ",");
char *secondString = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

That has the effect of slicing the existing string up in memory replacing the commas with `\0` and placing three pointers at the start of the three substrings. It has the advantage that it doesn't need to copy the contents of the string anywhere, so doesn't use any extra memory (other than the few bytes for the pointers).